# Should I enter my Office product key before running sysprep?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office-2007, clone, sysprep

I'm planning on cloning a Windows XP install, and am a little confused about `sysprep`. I know that it blanks out the XP product key, but what about other software?

If I install Office 2007 and enter a product key, then use `sysprep` and create an image, will I be able to enter a new product key in clones I create from the image? Or will they all have duplicate product keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is **no**, don't enter Microsoft Office product keys. They don't get blanked out by `sysprep` and you'll end up with every clone having the same product key.

However, it is fairly trivial (minor `regedit` session) to [remove the product key](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895456) so that you get prompted for another one when you start Office.